# Make Simple Accordion Scrollable

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to implement a simple accordion.

Is there a way I can make this scrollable?
When I add more elements and it fills up the screen it does not become scrollable, I thought by implementing a `Listview` would make it automatically scrollable

The XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#005555"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Location" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#005555"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Symptons" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#005555"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Location" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#005555"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Character" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#005555"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:text="Factors" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dip"
                android:background="#777777"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Item3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="340dip"
        android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `MainActivity` Code:

```
package com.accordion.accordion;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements
OnClickListener {
public OnLongClickListener longClickListner;
LinearLayout panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5;
TextView text1, text2, text3, text4, text5;
View openLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.accordian);

panel1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panel1);
panel2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panel2);
panel3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panel3);
panel4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panel4);
panel5 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panel5);

// panel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// panel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Log.v("CZ","height at first ..." + panel1.getMeasuredHeight());

text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
text4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text4);
text5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text5);

text1.setOnClickListener(this);
text2.setOnClickListener(this);
text3.setOnClickListener(this);
text4.setOnClickListener(this);
text5.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
hideOthers(v);
}

private void hideThemAll() {
if (openLayout == null)
    return;
if (openLayout == panel1)
    panel1.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToHide(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            500, panel1, true));
if (openLayout == panel2)
    panel2.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToHide(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            500, panel2, true));
if (openLayout == panel3)
    panel3.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToHide(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            500, panel3, true));
if (openLayout == panel4)
    panel4.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToHide(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            500, panel4, true));
if (openLayout == panel5)
    panel5.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToHide(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            500, panel5, true));
}

private void hideOthers(View layoutView) {
{
    int v;
    if (layoutView.getId() == R.id.text1) {
        v = panel1.getVisibility();
        if (v != View.VISIBLE) {
            panel1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.v("CZ", "height..." + panel1.getHeight());
        }

        // panel1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Log.v("CZ","again height..." + panel1.getHeight());
        hideThemAll();
        if (v != View.VISIBLE) {
            panel1.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToShow(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                    0.0f, 500, panel1, true));
        }
    } else if (layoutView.getId() == R.id.text2) {
        v = panel2.getVisibility();
        hideThemAll();
        if (v != View.VISIBLE) {
            panel2.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToShow(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                    0.0f, 500, panel2, true));
        }
    } else if (layoutView.getId() == R.id.text3) {
        v = panel3.getVisibility();
        hideThemAll();
        if (v != View.VISIBLE) {
            panel3.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToShow(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                    0.0f, 500, panel3, true));
        }
    } else if (layoutView.getId() == R.id.text4) {
        v = panel4.getVisibility();
        hideThemAll();
        if (v != View.VISIBLE) {
            panel4.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToShow(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                    0.0f, 500, panel4, true));
        }
    } else if (layoutView.getId() == R.id.text5) {
        v = panel5.getVisibility();
        hideThemAll();
        if (v != View.VISIBLE) {
            panel5.startAnimation(new ScaleAnimToShow(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                    0.0f, 500, panel5, true));
        }
    }
}
}

public class ScaleAnimToHide extends ScaleAnimation {

private View mView;

private LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

private int mMarginBottomFromY, mMarginBottomToY;

private boolean mVanishAfter = false;

public ScaleAnimToHide(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY,
        int duration, View view, boolean vanishAfter) {
    super(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
    setDuration(duration);
    openLayout = null;
    mView = view;
    mVanishAfter = vanishAfter;
    mLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    int height = mView.getHeight();
    mMarginBottomFromY = (int) (height * fromY)
            + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin - height;
    mMarginBottomToY = (int) (0 - ((height * toY) + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin))
            - height;

    Log.v("CZ", "height..." + height + " , mMarginBottomFromY...."
            + mMarginBottomFromY + " , mMarginBottomToY.."
            + mMarginBottomToY);
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
        Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
    if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
        int newMarginBottom = mMarginBottomFromY
                + (int) ((mMarginBottomToY - mMarginBottomFromY) * interpolatedTime);
        mLayoutParams.setMargins(mLayoutParams.leftMargin,
                mLayoutParams.topMargin, mLayoutParams.rightMargin,
                newMarginBottom);
        mView.getParent().requestLayout();
        // Log.v("CZ","newMarginBottom..." + newMarginBottom +
        // " , mLayoutParams.topMargin..." + mLayoutParams.topMargin);
    } else if (mVanishAfter) {
        mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
}

public class ScaleAnimToShow extends ScaleAnimation {

private View mView;

private LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

private int mMarginBottomFromY, mMarginBottomToY;

private boolean mVanishAfter = false;

public ScaleAnimToShow(float toX, float fromX, float toY, float fromY,
        int duration, View view, boolean vanishAfter) {
    super(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
    openLayout = view;
    setDuration(duration);
    mView = view;
    mVanishAfter = vanishAfter;
    mLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    int height = mView.getHeight();
    // mMarginBottomFromY = (int) (height * fromY) +
    // mLayoutParams.bottomMargin + height;
    // mMarginBottomToY = (int) (0 - ((height * toY) +
    // mLayoutParams.bottomMargin)) + height;

    mMarginBottomFromY = 0;
    mMarginBottomToY = height;

    Log.v("CZ", ".................height..." + height
            + " , mMarginBottomFromY...." + mMarginBottomFromY
            + " , mMarginBottomToY.." + mMarginBottomToY);
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
        Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
    if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
        int newMarginBottom = (int) ((mMarginBottomToY - mMarginBottomFromY) * `interpolatedTime)`
                - mMarginBottomToY;
        mLayoutParams.setMargins(mLayoutParams.leftMargin,
                mLayoutParams.topMargin, mLayoutParams.rightMargin,
                newMarginBottom);
        mView.getParent().requestLayout();
        // Log.v("CZ","newMarginBottom..." + newMarginBottom +
        // " , mLayoutParams.topMargin..." + mLayoutParams.topMargin);
    }
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem: Enclosing a LinearLayout in a scrollview since a scroll view can only surround one child class.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#005555"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Location" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panel1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#005555"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Symptons" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panel2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#005555"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Location" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panel3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#005555"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Character" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panel4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#005555"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Factors" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/panel5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"
                    android:background="#777777"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="Item3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="340dip"
            android:dividerHeight="0px"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach IMO would be to use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) . But if you really want to go ahead with the same xml that you have made, I will suggest you put the root LinearLayout inside a ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <!-- Your Linear Layout -->
</ScrollView>
```

Your Activity doesn't need to extend ListActivity, extending Activity would be enough.

Comment: **+1** for the `ExpandableListView` suggestion. That's what I'd suggest, too.

Comment: Adding a `ScrollView` in a layout that contains a `ListView` is not the best idea (especially since you have `fill_parent` as the `layout_height`).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `ListView` in the same layout, you should avoid adding a `ScrollView` as others have suggested. I would put the attributes in styles for each "panel" to remove redundant code. I would then add your layout as a [header](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)) to your `ListView` to make it scrollable.